# Is the group $\operatorname{Diff}^1_0(\mathbb R^d)$ connected?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, topological-groups

Is the group
$$ \operatorname{Diff}^1_0(\mathbb R^d) = \operatorname{Diff}^1(\mathbb R^d) \cap \big(\operatorname{Id}_{\mathbb R^d} + C^1_0(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d)\big) $$
connected? Here 
$$ C^1_0(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d) = \{ f \in C^1(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d) \,:\, |f(x)|\to 0,\, |Df(x)| \to 0\text{ as } x \to \infty \}\,, $$
and we equip $\operatorname{Diff}^1_0(\mathbb R^d)$ with the uniform $C^1$-topology.
Thus $\operatorname{Diff}^1_0(\mathbb R^d)$ consists of diffeomorphisms that decay to the identity towards infinity in the $C^1$-norm; in particular diffeomorphisms in $\operatorname{Diff}^1_0(\mathbb R^d)$ are orientation preserving.

The group $\operatorname{Diff}^1(\mathbb R^d)$ of $C^1$-diffeomorphisms equipped with the weak Whitney topology has two connected components—the orientation preserving and orientation reversing diffeomorphisms. To see this one can use the homotopy
$$ \varphi_t(x) = \frac 1t \big(\varphi(tx) - \varphi(0)\big) + t\varphi(0)\,, $$
with $\varphi_0(x) = D\varphi(0)x$. This is a deformation retraction of $\operatorname{Diff}^1(\mathbb R^d)$ unto $GL(\mathbb R^d)$. Since this homotopy works by pushing all nonlinearities out to infinity, it is not continuous in the strong Whitney topology or in the uniform $C^1$-topology used above.

Is there some other construction that can be used to show connectedness of $\operatorname{Diff}^1_0(\mathbb R^d)$? More generally, I am interested in whether the Sobolev diffeomorphism groups
$$ \mathcal D^s(\mathbb R^d) = \operatorname{Diff}^1(\mathbb R^d) \cap \big(\operatorname{Id}_{\mathbb R^d} + H^s(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d)\big)\,,$$
with $s > d/2+1$ are connected. However, a positive answer for $\operatorname{Diff}^1_0(\mathbb R^d)$ together with results from Palais' *Homotopy Theory of Infinite Dimensional Manifols* will imply the result for Sobolev diffeomorphisms.

Comment: Just a guess: it should be possible to move all nontriviality into the $r$-disk, so your group might have $\operatorname{Diff}(D^r,S^r)$ as a deformation retract. This group is well studied, see _concordances_ and _pseudoisotopies_, but I am no expert here.

Comment: I will check the details, but I believe you are right. We can deform the diffeomorphism to be constant outside a disk. I will look at the literature on the spaces $\operatorname{Diff}(D^r,S^r)$. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Another name for the space Sebastian mentions is the Pseudo-isotopy diffeomorphism group of a sphere ($S^{d-1}$).  It was studied by Cerf in the 70's and it is known to be connected provided $d \geq 8$.    It is not known to be connected in general.  For example, $d=5$ is an open problem as far as I know.

Comment: In your definition can you replace the limit conditions with a uniform condition, for example, $|f|<1/2$ for $|x|>2$ and $|Df|<1/2$ for $|x|>2$?  If so I believe these two spaces have the same homotopy-type.

Comment: @Ryan Budney, yes, I can also work with uniform conditions of $|f|$ and $|Df|$. That will still enable me to apply Palais' results to make conclusions about Sobolev diffeomorphisms. Could you sketch the argument why the space of diffeomorphisms satisfying uniform bounds has the same homotopy-type as the pseudo-isotopy diffeomorphism group of the sphere?

Comment: Outside of a disc, you use the straight-line homotopy $(1-t)\phi(x) + tx$.  Inside the disc you use isotopy-extension.

Comment: No, the space of diffeomorphisms supported in the unit $r$-disk is not the same as the space of pseudo-isotopies. The latter is connected for large values of $r$, as Ryan says. The former is very often not connected; for large values of $r$ its components correspond to types of exotic $(r+1)$-spheres.

Comment: To clarify, I was referring to what I ?thought? Sebastian was mentioning: the group of diffeomorphisms of $D^r$.  If you demand these diffeomorphisms are the identity on the boundary, you get what Tom is discussing.  If you allow the diffeomorphism to be free on the boundary you get what I was discussing (the pseudo-isotopy diffeomorphisms of a sphere of one lower dimension).